# Use of isInternalUSerID for Adapter Based Authentication

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am using IBM MobileFirst Studio Plugin 7.0 and was following the tutorials for adapter based authentication here [Documentation](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.0/authentication-security/adapter-based-authentication/).

I see that the isInternalUserID is not used to create the userIdentity object unlike the form base authenticator [Dcumentation](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.0/authentication-security/form-based-authentication/) . Can it be used? Or is it specifially so that the code to create the userIDentity needs to be done in the adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to the answer:

a) When using a custom security test, "isInternalUserID" is used to identify a particular realm as the one that will be used for creating user identity. If a realm is marked with "isInternalUserID" it means that only this realm is used for user identification.
There must be exactly one such realm for every security configuration that is applied to a mobile or web resource.

b) Adapter based authentication allows the flexibility to develop custom authentication logic within a MobileFirst adapter. This is why you see that userIdentity is created and assigned with adapter logic ( unlike the form based sample).
However, you will note that the generated identity is still assigned to the realm , that is marked "isInternalUserId" in the security test.

More details:

- [Understanding predefined Worklight authentication realms and security tests](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/understanding_predefined_worklight_authentication_realms_and_security_tests11?lang=en)
- [Security Tests](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_security_tests.html)
- [Implementing adapter-based authenticators](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_adapter_based_authenticator.html?lang=en)